# Managing Large conditional statements in Python

Tags: list, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a sort of broad general python/coding question that I'm hoping to get some direction on in terms of how to look into building this code.

I want to make a relatively simple GUI that will prompt the user initially for a part number, and based on the user input provide a second gui with a series of other prompts. These prompts can be anything from Serial ID # to any number of different Process #'s etc. but generally the 2nd set prompts are unique to the part number.

I can manage this relatively easy with a series of if statements such as:

if partNumber = 1:

//prompt for part number 123456

elif partNumber = 2:

//prompt for part number 2

My problem is I would imagine that if I were to have hundreds or thousands of prompts that this code will not only be incredibly inefficient, but it'd also be extremely cumbersome to write the individual prompts. What would be the appropriate way to manage a project like this if the prompts are relatively unique. Is there some way to manage this in lists or dictionaries? (frankly not very familiar with either) My experience is mostly using if statements and for loops for scripting and I've gotten by relatively well with that, but taking on larger projects has been a problem without knowing how such codes are generally structured.

Comment: Rather than something akin to what you've shown, you would typically defer resolving "what needs to happen" to either a lookup (e.g. a map/dict) or through proper object modelling + polymorphism. From the sound of the question, I would start brushing up OOP concepts.